# How to form sets of non-adjacent subgraphs from all possible subgraphs and the adjacency matrix?

Tags: partitions, group-theory, graphs-and-networks

I have connected graph with $72$ nodes.

The binary adjacency matrix of the connected graph is $A$. The size of $A$ is $72\times 72$ and its symmetric.

I have generated all possible subgraphs ($17000$ subgraphs) with 6 nodes. Lets say $M$ is the matrix of size $17000\times 6$, where row $i$ defines the indices of the nodes in subgraph $i$.

Now, I need to find all possible sets of 3 subgraphs where the subgraphs in each set are non-adjacent. For exaple, let $S=\left\{\left\{a,b,c,d,e,f\right\},\left\{g,h,i,j,k,l\right\},\left\{m,n,o,p,q,r\right\}\right\}$ is one of the possible sets. Then, $\left\{a,b,c,d,e,f\right\}$ is a subgraph with nodes index $a,b,c,d,e,f$. Likewise, $\left\{g,h,i,j,k,l\right\}$ and $\left\{m,n,o,p,q,r\right\}$ are the remaining two subgraphs in set $S$.

Now, $S$ needs to be formed in such a way that any node in one of the subgraphs whould not be adjacent to any node in the remnaing two subgraphs in set $S$. In simple words, the subgraphs in any set must be non-adjacent.

Any suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find sets of non-adjacent subgraphs from all the subgraphs available?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185809/how-to-find-sets-of-non-adjacent-subgraphs-from-all-the-subgraphs-available)

Comment: @halmir The link is broken